# Save list of states and counties in session or not

Tags: php, session

Hi I need some advice from you. I have two tables: states and counties, each state can have one or more counties related. I have 2 dropdown menus one for states and the other for counties. Every time the user select a state an ajax request is made, query the database and look for the corresponding counties of that state. The user can also add more counties if they are not in the database.

I'm thinking of save all states and counties in PHP user session, in order to not query the database all the time, the problem comes when someone adds a new county I can update session variable for that user but the others users don't know if there is a new county in the database.

Do you think is a good idea to save that in session or query the database several times? I'm also open to other solutions.
Thanks

Comment: Don't store that information in the SESSION, store it in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database is properly indexed, there should be no need to do this.

With significant amounts of data, it's even possible that storing the data in a session slows down the experience overall, as the session data file has to be loaded and parsed on every request that uses the session.

Comment: So if tables are properly indexed there is no need to use cache?

Comment: @Jorge *in this specific case,* yes. It does not make sense to store the list in the session. In other scenarios, a separate caching layer may well make sense.

Comment: That's the kind of things you don't learn at school, thank you

Comment: Note - 'caching' data in a session is not the same as caching a query

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of session data. Session data is stored on the server. You'd be sending that data back to the user from your server either way, but it would be replicated in the session of each user who needs that data.

I'd implement it as a lookup as the list is so long, and will likely grow, and worry about performance later if it becomes an issue. You could cache the query and results to save it running on the db each time, and clear it to be cached again if a new county is added. Alternatively, you could keep the list stored in an array in php, but that's really ideal for smaller enums.

Comment: no, thats not how sessions work. you seem to be confusing sessions with cookies